# Expanding an ASP.Net TreeView node from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, code-behind, expand

I'm learning how to access the controls of an ASP.Net master page and trying to expand a particular TreeView node. I'm doing this from another page that is not a master page.

objContentPlaceHolder, objLoginView and objTreeView all have a value as confirmed by using the debugger.

Can you look at this code and let us know why the code in the for loop is not executing? It reaches the for loop but just skips over the for loop at that point.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim objContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
    Dim objLoginView As LoginView
    Dim objTreeView As TreeView

    objContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderBody"), ContentPlaceHolder)

    If Not objContentPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then

        objLoginView = CType(objContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("loginViewMain"), LoginView)

        If Not objLoginView Is Nothing Then
            objTreeView = CType(objLoginView.FindControl("TreeViewMain"), TreeView)

            ' Make sure all nodes for Maintenance are expanded.
            '--------------------------------------------------
            For Each treenode As TreeNode In objTreeView.Nodes
                If treenode.Text = "Maintenance" Then
                    treenode.Expand()
                End If
            Next treenode
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*** Update ***

I changed the page load event handler to a PreRenderComplete event handler and would you believe it worked? Not sure why PreRender didn't but that was it. Thanks again everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public Sub TreeView_TreeNodeDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeNodeEventArgs  )
       dim mapNode as SiteMapNode =  e.Node.DataItem as SiteMapNode
       If mapNode.Title = "Maintenance" then
           e.Node.Expand()
       End if
   End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim objContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
        Dim objLoginView As LoginView
        Dim objTreeView As TreeView

        objContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderBody"), ContentPlaceHolder)

        If Not objContentPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then

            objLoginView = CType(objContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("loginViewMain"), LoginView)

            If Not objLoginView Is Nothing Then
                objTreeView = CType(objLoginView.FindControl("TreeViewMain"), TreeView)
                objTreeView.TreeNodeDataBound += TreeView_TreeNodeDataBound 
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I will try it and let you know how it works.

Comment: I found that "expandTreeNode(treenode)" will not execute because it's in the for loop that get skipped over.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen I guess your treeview is not bound at that time, you should move this code in a pre_render event handler

Comment: Ok, I will try that. The TreeView is set up from a Web.sitemap file.

Comment: Just changed it to a pre_render handler and the for loop is still being skipped over.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen maybe you can try another approach, with event handler. Updated my answer. Sorry for the poor syntax

Comment: If gives this error on the objTreeView.TreeNodeDataBound += TreeView_TreeNodeDataBound() line: Error 1 'Public Event TreeNodeDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event. Can you show the coding with a RaiseEvent statement?

Comment: I found a PreRenderComplete event and would you believe it worked? Not sure why PreRender didn't but that was it. Thanks again everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like your logic is only checking the root nodes. When dealing with hierarchical data, you need to employ recursive logic to ensure that the entire structure gets evaluated.

Something like this is what you need:

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each node As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
        ExpandNodeByValue("Maintenance", node)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ExpandNodeByValue(value As String, parentNode As TreeNode)
    For Each childNode As TreeNode In parentNode.ChildNodes
        If childNode.Value.ToLower() = value.ToLower() Then
            childNode.Expand()
        End If
        If childNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
            ExpandNodeByValue(value, childNode)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I would also suggest using a `DirectCast` instead of `CType`, at least temporarily, to ensure that the control is being found. You would implement that like this:

```
Dim objTreeView as TreeView = DirectCast(objLoginView.FindControl("TreeViewMain"), TreeView)
If objTreeView IsNot Nothing Then
    'The control was found
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes, it's the root node. We would like to expand just the root node "Maintenance" if possible. I'm able to collapse the "Maintenance" node from the code-behind file of the master page but it seems tricky to expand them when accessing the TreeView from a page that's not the master page. I tried the code but it did not recognize ".Tag".

Comment: I changed node.Tag.ToString() to node.Text.ToString() because I think that was what you were trying to show. Also can you show the coding for FindChildNode()  ?

Comment: I tried this with just the "for each" based on your code:                 objTreeView = CType(objLoginView.FindControl("TreeViewMain"), TreeView)

                For Each node As TreeNode In objTreeView.Nodes
                Next
but the "for each" gets skipped.

Comment: Are you sure that it's finding the control? Also, please verify that the control has been populated at the point you're executing the code.

Comment: Yes, quite sure because I placed a break point on the For loop and when I do a "step into" it just jumps out of the loop and never touches the "Next" statement. If it's ok with everyone, I will post all of the coding for the TreeView if needed.

Comment: Can you verify what the node count is using the debugger?

Comment: It shows 0. Not sure why since it's loaded from the web.sitemap and the treeview is displayed with the all the nodes on the web page. I can also expand and collapse the TreeView with the mouse without any problems.

Comment: Also, try using `DirectCast` instead of `CType`. I believe `CType` will return an instance of the object regardless. I suspect that it's not actually finding the control.

Comment: Can you show what the coding would look like using DirectCast? I will check back in about 15 minutes. Thanks for all the time you are taking to help.